# HTML - Display animation while JavaScript loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, loading

I'm using this JavaScript to preload few images on my website.

```
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image()
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
        }
    }

    preload(
        "img/1.png",
        "img/hover.png",
        "img/image.png",
        "img/work1.png"
    )
```

This code is linked in HEAD of the site.
But when someone is visiting my website he waits for few second's while images are loaded and in that time he sees blank (white) website until JS files are loaded. I want to make that when someone visit my website he see a "Loading progess bar" or message that say "Wati until page is loaded" etc. Without a blank index page where JavaScript is linked

Comment: Your ```preload()``` only loads the images. You need to write more code to manipulate the DOM and display the content you want (while images are loading, and after they upload).

Answer (score 0):

Unless an accurate progress bar is actually helpful to your users you are probably better off simply use an animated gif that gets hidden after your loading functions finish.  Something like this:
[image: Loading Animation]

Put the gif on the top of your `index.html file`. Something like

```
<div id="loading-gif"><img src="/path/to/gif"></div>
```

Then when your content loads, simply execute something like

```
document.getElementById("loading-gif").style.display = 'none';
```

Note, license information for the above image is located [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:InternetSlowdown_Day.gif).